# Compile function returning postLink only - is it anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am seeing this a lot in directives:

```
 compile: function(elm, attrs, transclude) {
            return function postLink(scope, elm, attrs, tabsetCtrl) {
                     // do something with transclude function
                   }
          }
```

and I want to confirm my understanding that it is an deprecated form doing things because older version of Angular didn't have transclude as parameter in link function
and it's better (more readable) to do now:

```
link: function (scope, elm, attrs, tabsetCtrl, transclude) {
        // do something with transclude function
      }
```

Is there any difference between these two when there's no other body of compile function?
(I checked in code samples and both ways work the same, but maybe there is something that causes the first form to be better than second)

Comment: Both functions do the same thing, and first function is not deprecated. Transclusion is available only if you say that your directive is transcluded. Beacause link -> post link. You use compile only if you need an prelinking function or you need a dom transformation before your link function is executed.

Comment: No, it's not correct - from Angular docs
 
"Note: The transclude function that is passed to the compile function is deprecated, as it e.g. does not know about the right outer scope. Please use the transclude function that is passed to the link function instead."

I'm aware of everything you wrote, but it's not the answer for my question. I asked actually why would anyone use the first form when the second is much more readable and does the same. And a lots of people are using the first form.

Comment: You didn't read the answer. I sead: First function is not deprecated.
And your answer: You use compile only if you need an prelinking function or you need a dom transformation before your link function is executed.

Comment: ?!? I quoted you manual. First form of compile function with tranclude function as param IS DEPRECATED!!!and i didnt ask about compile function in general.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn - Take ANY directive (eg tab in angular-bootstrap) with first form and change it to the second without changing the body and notice the difference. No difference? Hmmm.... Then Why use it?? And if you really have to answer (please dont anymore) - give me one sample when first FORM is better than the second.

Answer (score 0):

You still don't get it. You only use a compile when you need a pre link and the only time you'd want to use a pre link is when you need to perform some preparation on the scope before any child elements compile.
Here is example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/x9FeRULhjJVxGWDDfAkk?p=preview
I want to present you what is difference between compile and link function so you can understand when compile is required. Because in your case compile is not required its the same as link but in newer angular your return

```
{
    transclude: true,
    compile:  function(elm, attrs) {
          // you can do transformation of element before link also here
          // which you cannot do in link function eg.
          elem.addClass('testclass');
          // or like i did in example on link
          elem.prepend('<span style="color:red;"> {{value}} </span> ');

          return function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

          }
    } 
}
```

but in your example without transformations is the same as link function

```
 {
    transclude: true,
    link:  return function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

    }
 }
```

but when you set both link function is ignored.

Its this anti pattern ?
No its not. Because you can do element transformation before link is executed.

[image: Burn]